# storing files in s3 using Python boto

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, boto

I have a list of dicts (ex. `[{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}, {'e': 'f', 'g': 'h'}]`) and I want to store this in s3 using Python boto package.

One way is to iterate through the list, writing to a file object `f`, such that each line of `f` is a json object. Then I could use `key.set_contents_from_file(f)`. Is the correct/best way to do it?

It seems like writing to a local file is an unnecessary middle step, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To skip the writing to file step, you could use `key.set_contents_from_string(str)` to PUT your dicts' values directly.

See: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key

(CTRL+F for `set_contents_from_string`)

Another roundabout way (to avoid writing to disk) would be to use `set_contents_from_stream`, and create an in-memory "file" (using StringIO  and such), which you pass to that function.

Comment: Hmm, but that takes in a string `str` instead of a list (a list of non-strings at that), and I'm not sure how I could write one line at a time that way. Any thoughts? (I want to read one line at a time so that something reading the file from s3 can do it one line at a time, without having to load the whole thing possibly).

Comment: Unless you expect your json files to be huge, this sounds a little bit like an unnecessary optimization. You could `json.dumps(your_dict)` to convert it to JSON, then put the entire JSON to S3? Then any clients who GET the JSON can parse it as JSON. If you REALLY want to stream it JSON object-by-JSON object, then you can use a "streaming JSON parser".

Comment: Good point, but I actually do expect the json files to be huge, and actually have had to chunk up data sets in order not surpass the memory limit of the managed machines we are hosting on. So how about this "streaming JSON parser"?

Comment: Interesting. If materializing the dict in memory is fine, you could try using python's StringIO to treat the string as a file ,then use `set_content_from_file` (or `from_stream`). As for streaming JSON parser in Python, there are libraries for this, but I'm not familiar with them. Treating it as a Python generator probably would also work.

Comment: If you wanted something that doesn't materialize it as a string in memory but want to use `set_content_from_stream`, you could write a file-like class that wraps your list of dicts, and pass that into the function. Your file-like class would return one dict at a line, converted to a JSON string. You probably need to implement `tell()` and `read()` at the least.

Comment: Which is faster: writing to a file object with f.write() (in order to then do `set_content_from_file`) OR stringifying with json.dumps() (in order to then do `set_contents_from_string`)?

Comment: It depends on a lot of factors. Btw, you can write to a file-like object in memory and `set_content_from_file` that way without writing to disk. But what is fastest is probably writing a file-like class that wraps your list of dicts, which you pass into `set_contents_from_stream`. However, this adds a layer of complexity that you might not be interested in.